# Add button in Internet Explorer from C# application and copy content

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, interop, com-interop

I want my C# application to open an Internet Explorer window. So far I have figured out how I'm doing:

```
using SHDocVw

Type oType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application");

if (oType != null)
    return (InternetExplorer)Activator.CreateInstance(oType);
```

Now I want to remove all unnecessary buttons and menus in Internet Explorer and instead, I want to add a custom button in the toolbar. When the user presses the button, all information on the current page is copied to my C# programs. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about hosting a web browser control inside your application?  You might want to take a look at the WebBrowser class: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)